# Detect changes in array

Tags: vb.net

Let's assume we have an array defined like the following:

```
Dim Data1 As Object()
Dim Data2 As Double()
```

I would like to find a way to manage changes in an Array, such as:

```
//Example #1
Redim Data2(5)

//Example #2
Data2(0) = 3.14
```

My idea was to create a `CustomArray(of T)`, which inherits from `System.Array`, and raise an event at the right time. Unfortunately, however, the `System.Array` class cannot be inherited...

I know that for this kind of operations it would be better to use other data structures ([ObservableCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=net-6.0)), but I need to keep the arrays functions (for example `Redim` and `Ubound`): by creating a new class (with all array functions), I would still not be able to use Ubound, which requires a `System.Array`.

Is there a solution?

Comment: Linq SequenceEqual?

Comment: List.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=net-6.0

Comment: @dbasnett You can't use `Redim` or `Ubound` on a List...

Comment: @CaiusJard it's an idea, but I'd rather not make a copy of the data every time...

Comment: @Calaf - see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Ubound and Redim can be simulated.  A short example,

```
    Dim foo As New List(Of String) From {"A", "B", "C", "Z"}
    Dim uBnd As Integer = foo.Count - 1 ' UBound

    ' redim - grow
    foo.AddRange({"d", "e", "f", "x"})

    ' redim - decrease
    foo.RemoveRange(1, 3)
```

Comment: I know, but that's not what I asked for. I need to keep the `Redim array` / `Ubound(array)` syntax.

Comment: @Calaf - sorry.  Didn't know you were married to the idea.  Just trying to point out an alternative, didn't warrant a negative vote.

Comment: An answer is an answer: for suggestions there are comments. I'm not looking for a tip on how to use basic data structures, but on how to solve a specific problem (which your answer does not do). If the negative vote is the problem, you can delete the answer.

Comment: Didn't say my answer was a comment and not all suggestions, especially when code is involved, are portrayed well in comments.  Good luck.